# Lumia 635 Podcast Downloads Keep Resetting

Tags: lumia, 8.1-update-1, podcast, lumia-635

I keep having problems trying to download podcasts using either the built in Windows 8.1 podcast app or Castcenter (I have also tried others with the same problem but I can't name them off the top of my head!).

95% of the time when I leave my phone to download podcasts, (either with the app open or minimised) when I come back to it the download either hasn't progressed or most often any progress that there was before I left the phone will have been lost and the download will restart. I've got battery saver set to only come on at 20% battery and this happens even when the phone is left charging.

The same thing happens when I leave the app (either with the windows button or the task switcher) and continue using the phone for something else.

Can anyone help? I've try googling it but there doesnt seem to have been anyone else having the same issue (that I can find!).

Cheers,
David